# why classcastException is not thrown at compile time when downcasted?

Tags: java, casting, classcastexception, downcast

Consider the example below. line 5 of `main`(commented) throws `ClassCastException` at `Runtime`.
Line 4 is a valid `cast` because v1 has "knowledge" of car". In the same token, shouldn't line 5 give `compile time` error since it has "knowledge of v2" being a vehicle and not car and hence throw compile time error saying "hey I have no knowledge of car, I am a vehicle, you can't be cast to a car".

During compile time, `Vehicle v1 = new Car()`, a `new Car` is not created. but v1 has knowledge that it is a car correct?

```
class Vehicle {
}

class Bus extends Vehicle {
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
}

public class UpcastDownCast {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehicle v1 = new Car(); // line 1
        Vehicle v2 = new Vehicle();// line 2
        // compile time error. Type mis-match
        Car c0 = v1; // line 3
        // v1 has knowledge of Car due to line 1
        Car c1 = (Car) v1;//line 4
        // Runtime Exception. v2 has no knowledge of car
        Car c2 = (Car) v2;//line 5

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Downcasting/Upcasting error at compile time & runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180861/downcasting-upcasting-error-at-compile-time-runtime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java doesn't propagate information like that.  As soon as you say `Vehicle v2 = new Vehicle()`, Java forgets any knowledge of what `v2` is other than "it's `Vehicle` or some subtype of `Vehicle`.

Comment: `Car c0 = v1; ` this is valid because car is subtype of vehicle?

Comment: No, that's not valid, because there's no cast to enforce the check that `v1` is actually a `Car`.

Answer (score 3):

No, the compiler doesn't know what the actual object being referenced by `v1` or `v2`. It only knows the reference type. The actual object comes into picture at runtime. So, the compiler wouldn't and it shouldn't give you compiler error for that.

Comment: Additionally, that's the point where IDE's have their strengths - static code analysis where you (OP) would surely get the probably erroneous code marked.

Comment: @Smutje Perhaps. But that will depend upon which particular code analysis tool you're using. Moreover, the rules should be configurable.

Comment: I thought of/used IntelliJ and Eclipse Checkstyle so far.