# Is it possible to achieve run-time/compile-time polymorphism using downcasting?

Tags: java, dynamic, polymorphism, downcast, upcasting

I know that upcasting can be used to achieve run-time polymorphism in java. But I am curious about a similar possibility in case of downcasting. If polymorphism is possible in case of downcasting, then is it runtime or compiletime?

The below code is an example of upcasting. It is also resulting in runtime polymorphism.

```
class Bike{  
  void run(){System.out.println("running");}  
}  
class BMW extends Bike{  
  void run(){System.out.println("running safely with 60km");}  

  public static void main(String args[]){  
    BMW b = new BMW(); 
    Bike c = (Bike)b;//upcasting 
    b.run();  
 }  
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "to achieve" here - upcasting isn't what makes polymorphism happen in Java. It's really unclear to me what you're asking here, I'm afraid.

Comment: Jon - Please have a look at the code that I have added to the question. Can we get a similar kind of polymorphism or method overriding using downcasting? That is my question?

Comment: It's still not at all clear what you're actually trying to achieve. If you're trying to use `BMW b = (BMW) new Bike();` then that's going to fail at execution time... (I wouldn't call what you've written upcasting anyway, personally - it's just an implicit conversion.)

Comment: Jon - now I guess the code is more representive of upcasting. Downcasting can be achieved using instanceof operator in java. Here's a link explaining it http://www.javatpoint.com/downcasting-with-instanceof-operator

Comment: I'm aware of what the `instanceof` operator does, but that doesn't downcast. It can tell you whether it's *safe* to downcast, but it doesn't perform the downcast itself. Downcasting would be the kind of code I showed you: `(BMW) new Bike()`.

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14181046/1814867